# Table View Javafx doesn't show data correctly. The data in table is invisible

Tags: java, mysql, database, uitableview, javafx

A few days I can't find the reason of incorrect display data in ma JavaFX table view. When I start proggram my table looks
[Befor popullating table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geIUw.png)

When I press button "Update table" table looks:
[Look after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CpJV.jpg)

I created method with filter where I can do search data in the table. And when I try to find some word that I know exist in database, it find it but not show again. For instance, I put to DB my email address: dpopov88@me.com, and when i write it in search text field nothing changes in table view, but if i try find and specially do mistake after 5 letter table shows that "No content in table".
[No content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dvau6.jpg)

**User class:**

```
package application.controllers;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Users {

    private SimpleStringProperty id;
    private SimpleStringProperty fn;
    private SimpleStringProperty ln;
    private SimpleStringProperty lo;
    private SimpleStringProperty pa;
    private SimpleStringProperty em;
    private SimpleStringProperty ro;

    public Users(String id, String firstName, String lastName, String login, String password, String email, String role) {
        this.id = new SimpleStringProperty(id);
        this.fn = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
        this.ln = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
        this.lo = new SimpleStringProperty(login);
        this.pa = new SimpleStringProperty(password);
        this.em = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
        this.ro = new SimpleStringProperty(role);
    }   
    public String getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id.set(id);
    }
    public String getFn() {
        return fn.get();
    }
    public void setFn(String fn) {
        this.fn.set(fn);
    }
    public String getLn() {
        return ln.get();
    }
    public void setLn(String ln) {
        this.ln.set(ln);
    }
    public String getLo() {
        return lo.get();
    }
    public void setLo(String lo) {
        this.lo.set(lo);
    }
    public String getPa() {
        return pa.get();
    }
    public void setPa(String pa) {
        this.pa.set(pa);
    }
    public String getEm() {
        return em.get();
    }
    public void setEm(String em) {
        this.em.set(em);
    }
    public String getRo() {
        return ro.get();
    }
    public void setRo(String ro) {
        this.ro.set(ro);
    }
```

**AdministratorViewController class:**

```
package application.adminview;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import application.controllers.ConnectionToSQL;
import application.controllers.Users;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.SortedList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class AdministratorViewController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button employeeUpdateButton;
    @FXML
    private TextField employeeSearchField;
    @FXML
    TableView<Users> employeeTableView;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Users, String> id;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Users, String> firstName;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Users, String> lastName;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Users, String> login;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Users, String> password;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Users, String> email;
    @FXML
    TableColumn<Users, String> role;
    ObservableList<Users> data;
    FilteredList<Users> filteredData;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        employeeTableView.setItems(data);
        id.setCellValueFactory( c-> new SimpleStringProperty(c.getValue().getId()));
        firstName.setCellValueFactory(c-> new SimpleStringProperty(c.getValue().getFn()));
        lastName.setCellValueFactory(c-> new SimpleStringProperty(c.getValue().getLn()));
        login.setCellValueFactory(c-> new SimpleStringProperty(c.getValue().getLo()));
        password.setCellValueFactory(c-> new SimpleStringProperty(c.getValue().getPa()));
        email.setCellValueFactory(c-> new SimpleStringProperty(c.getValue().getEm()));
        role.setCellValueFactory(c-> new SimpleStringProperty(c.getValue().getId()));
        employeeTableView.setItems(data);
        mainGridPane.toFront();
        mainPane.toFront();
        employeeTableView.setFixedCellSize(1);

    @FXML
    private void loadDataToEmployeeTableView(ActionEvent event) {
        try {
            data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            ResultSet rs = ConnectionToSQL.getConnection().createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
            while (rs.next()) {
                data.add(new Users(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4), rs.getString(5),
                        rs.getString(6), rs.getString(7)));
                filteredData = new FilteredList<>(data, e -> true);
                System.out.println(rs.getString("idusers") + rs.getString("FirstName") + rs.getString("LastName")
                        + rs.getString("Login") + rs.getString("Password") + rs.getString("Email")
                        + rs.getString("Role"));
            }
            employeeTableView.setItems(data);
        } catch (SQLException exc) {
            System.err.println("Error" + exc);
        }
        System.out.println("Done");
        employeeTableView.setItems(data);
    }
```

**Variable ObservableList data** after method start stores data from DB. I checked it.

```
  <TableView fx:id="employeeTableView" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                     <columnResizePolicy>
                        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                     </columnResizePolicy>
                     <columns>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="id" prefWidth="75.0" text="id" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="firstName" prefWidth="75.0" text="firstName" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="lastName" prefWidth="75.0" text="lastName" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="login" prefWidth="75.0" text="login" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="password" prefWidth="75.0" text="password" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="email" prefWidth="75.0" text="email" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="role" prefWidth="75.0" text="role" />
                     </columns></TableView>
```

Comment: Oh, God, I got it myself. ))) 
The reason was only one string: ** employeeTableView.setFixedCellSize(1); ** I deleted it and its work

Comment: You should write an answer and possibly remove unrelated parts of the code from your question (e.g. sorting db access, some of the columns, some of the controller fields not related to this question...).